# Fiddler and flash?

Tags: flash, fiddler

i'm trying to make SwfUpload working. In some cases, I've a strange behaviour.

So I would like to inspect the flows sended and received by the flash component. And I've tryed to use fiddler to do that, but I can't capture data comming from flash or going to flash.

Is there a way to do that ?

(note, i'm working on http://localhost with php)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in the FAQ: http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic.

FWIW: I'm not sure WireShark would work, since when you're hitting http://localhost, the request bypasses most of the Network stack.

Comment: New URL http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost

Answer (score 0):

Sure Fiddler is setup to intercept everything? (Tools -> Fiddler Options ->Connection -> Monitor All)

If it isn't working [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will capture & display all TCP traffic on your machine with a little bit more effort.